# Is it possible to check if elements of a tensor are out of boundaries?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

Is it possible to check if elements of a tensor are out of boundaries using `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` on **PyTorch**, **GPU** approach?

Example (`check limits`):

```
for i in range(pop):
    if (x[i]>xmax):
        x[i]=xmax
    elif (x[i]<xmin):
        x[i]=xmin
```

I tried the following, but did not speed up:

```
idxmax    = (x > xmax) # elements that are bigger that upper limit
idxmim    = (x < min)  # elements that are smaller that upper limit
x[idxmax] = xmax
x[idxmin] = xmin
```

If not, is it possible to do this `check limits` part, using only the CPU? How?

Comment: please mention what speed you are expecting and what you are getting. I don't know, if you are doing a simple thing, you can do them in CPU. why are even you trying to use GPU?

Comment: My main goal is not to use PSO to solve simple objective function.I will use it to solve complex problems with huge amount of data (lots of big matrices,etc). But first, as you may understand, I need to learn the basics.

Comment: Then you don't need to bother about speed now as you are testing with small input. When you will do a large-scale experiment, you will ultimately see the advantage of using GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a CPU copy of tensor `x`, do your operations and then push the tensor to GPU memory again.

```
x = x.cpu()  # get the CPU copy
# do your operations
x = x.cuda() # move the object back to cuda memory
```